# Salesforce Flow not showing up in record

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-flow

I have debugged it and the flow returns expected results...just not showing up.  Where do I look next?

Any ideas or where to begin troubleshooting would be helpful.  TIA

Brian

I have debugged it and the flow returns expected results

the field is not showing the date as expected inside the actual record.

I chose in the Decision tree that when any of the conditions are met (OR)

When the record is updated.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the flow? Do you have an update node at the end? Or is it a "fast field updates" flow (runs before save)? Does your record even change lastmodifieddate?